# Is there a way to round numbers into a reader friendly format? (e.g. $1.1k)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding, currency

Much like the Stackoverlow reputation rounding, I'm hoping to do the same thing with currency

$1,000 => 1k

$1,000,000 => 1m

How can I achieve this in JavaScript (preferably in jQuery)?

Comment: This currently doesn't qualify as an acceptable code-golf question. see
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24258 You need a few more test cases, to make it community wiki and finally you should accept the shortest (in code size) answer. Single language code-golfs are boring, you should also open it to other languages

Comment: David created a [code-golf] version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692323/code-golf-friendly-number-abbreviator

Comment: Thanks guys -- as you can see I'm new to Stack Overflow.  I'm excited that you all think this is an interesting problem!

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Here is a simple function to do it:

```js
function abbrNum(number, decPlaces) {
  // 2 decimal places => 100, 3 => 1000, etc
  decPlaces = Math.pow(10, decPlaces);

  // Enumerate number abbreviations
  var abbrev = ["k", "m", "b", "t"];

  // Go through the array backwards, so we do the largest first
  for (var i = abbrev.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    // Convert array index to "1000", "1000000", etc
    var size = Math.pow(10, (i + 1) * 3);

    // If the number is bigger or equal do the abbreviation
    if (size <= number) {
      // Here, we multiply by decPlaces, round, and then divide by decPlaces.
      // This gives us nice rounding to a particular decimal place.
      number = Math.round(number * decPlaces / size) / decPlaces;

      // Handle special case where we round up to the next abbreviation
      if ((number == 1000) && (i < abbrev.length - 1)) {
        number = 1;
        i++;
      }

      // Add the letter for the abbreviation
      number += abbrev[i];

      // We are done... stop
      break;
    }
  }

  return number;
}
console.log(abbrNum(1200, 3))
```

Outputs:

```
abbrNum(12 , 1)          => 12
abbrNum(0 , 2)           => 0
abbrNum(1234 , 0)        => 1k
abbrNum(34567 , 2)       => 34.57k
abbrNum(918395 , 1)      => 918.4k
abbrNum(2134124 , 2)     => 2.13m
abbrNum(47475782130 , 2) => 47.48b
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/SbqKL/

Comment: this feels golfy. how small can we get this function?

Comment: FUND IT.

Seriously though, I'd love to see that in a golf thread.

Comment: @ Damien Wilson: Code-golf tag added. What do you mean by fund?

Comment: @Baloney: I was just making it flexible.  Do what is best for your application.  An "appropriate cut-off" point is often subjective and/or application specific.

Comment: Code golf version posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692323/code-golf-number-formatter). For contributing members of OP question: feel free to change the parameters of the question...I had a difficult time deciding the limitations/boundaries.

Comment: `function a(n,d){x=(''+n).length,p=Math.pow,d=p(10,d);x-=x%3;return Math.round(n*d/p(10,x))/d+" kMGTPE"[x/3]}` --- Sufficiently Golfed (108)? :)

Comment: `abbrNum(999950, 0) => 1000k`, yeah it only happens 50 / 1M times but still.

Comment: @crizCraig: Good catch!  I added a special case handler for that in the code.  There is probably a more efficient way to do it, but it works for now.

Comment: **104 bytes** `function(a,b,c,d){c=(''+a).length;d=Math.pow;b=d(10,b);return((a*b/d(10,c-=c%3))+.5|0)/b+' kMGTPE'[c/3]}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25612036/1729885

Comment: I have an optimised version of the above code in objective C over here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35742809/1920799.    ...   .... @JeffB : your method doesn't work for negative numbers. you need to use the following   .....       if(size <= Math.abs(Math.round(number)))   ..... 

instead of .....
if(size <= number) .........

Which has an extra benefit of removing your code block of 'Handle special case where we round up to the next abbreviation'

Comment: can without round ?  abbrNum(1432, 1); => 1.4k;  abbrNum(1992, 1); => 1.9k

Comment: @padavan Just change the `Math.round` above to `Math.floor`.

Answer (score 25):

```js
var floor=Math.floor, abs=Math.abs, log=Math.log, round=Math.round, min=Math.min;
var abbrev = ['k', 'Mil', 'Bil']; // abbreviations in steps of 1000x; extensible if need to edit

function rnd(n, precision) {
    var prec = 10**precision;
    return round(n*prec)/prec;
}

function format(n) {
    var base = floor(log(abs(n))/log(1000));
    var suffix = abbrev[min(abbrev.length-1, base-1)];
    base = abbrev.indexOf(suffix) + 1;
    return suffix ? rnd(n/1000**base,2)+suffix : ''+n;
}
```

Demo:

```
> tests = [-1001, -1, 0, 1, 2.5, 999, 1234, 
           1234.5, 1000001, 10**9, 10**12]
> tests.forEach(function(x){ console.log(x,format(x)) })

-1001 "-1k"
-1 "-1"
0 "0"
1 "1"
2.5 "2.5"
999 "999"
1234 "1.23k"
1234.5 "1.23k"
1000001 "1Mil"
1000000000 "1Bil"
1000000000000 "1000Bil"
```

Comment: This one is the best since it works with negative numbers too

Comment: @shrekuu: seems to be passed just fine as `round`ing to two decimal places in  `round(n/pow(...), 2)`; feel free to clarify

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. Failed to read it more carefully. I will delete my previous comment to avoid misleading.