# 1000000 to 1M and 1000 to 1K and so on in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way round numbers into a friendly format? (e.g. $1.1k)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685911/is-there-a-way-round-numbers-into-a-friendly-format-e-g-1-1k)
>   [How to format numbers similar to Stack Overflow reputation format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177855/how-to-format-numbers-similar-to-stack-overflow-reputation-format)

I have long numbers in JS and I'd like to make them appear in a shorter, and more eaisier to understand way..

So:

```
1,000,000 = 1M

1,200,000 = 1.2M

1,450 = 1.45K and so on...
```

Any ideas how I could do this in JS or JQuery?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just for fun, check out [Code Golf: Friendly Number Abbreviator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692323/code-golf-friendly-number-abbreviator)

The shortest JS answer:

```
function m(n,d){x=(''+n).length,p=Math.pow,d=p(10,d)
x-=x%3
return Math.round(n*d/p(10,x))/d+" kMGTPE"[x/3]}
```

p.s. this is probably not the fastest or best solution.

Duplicate: [Is there a way to round numbers into a reader friendly format? (e.g. $1.1k)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685911/is-there-a-way-round-numbers-into-a-friendly-format-e-g-1-1k)

Comment: so I'm guessing `n` is the number, but what is `d` for? thanks

Comment: `d` is the number of decimal places for abbreviation. Note: the code-golf solution leaks `x` and `p` into the global scope...not a good thing.

Comment: but i need to use this dynamically and i only have the number to play with. Any way I could get away without inputting the decimal places?

Comment: `d` is the number of decimal place to *display in the abbreviation*, not the input number. If you want to display 1.2k for `1200` you would call the function like this: `m(1200,1)`

Comment: I think this is for formatting drive space, no? G = gig's instead of B = billions? Whats P and E?

Comment: G is for billion, P is for quadrillion, and E is for quintillion. Check out this wikipedia article on metric prefixes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) for the reasons why things are this way.

Comment: Why for this ` console.log(m(120000,4));`  the output is 0.12M instead of 120k ?

Comment: JS has in-build function for this see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66940065/14112947)