# iOS: Convert Integer with value over Thousand to a shorter Integer with letter 'K'

Tags: ios, integer

I would like to convert a big Integer (over 1 Thousand) to a String with 'K' at the end like in Instagram:
[image: Example:]

Comment: Look into the `NSByteCountFormatter` class. Much easier than all of the links you've been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *intWithK = myint >= 1000 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dk", myint / 1000] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myint]
```

Should work :)

I your integer (I called it `myint`) is greater or equal to 1000 it'll divide it by 1000 and add "k", but won't do anything if it's smaller

Comment: The improved answer is perfect!

Comment: That will handle things for a very specific need, but a better, more thorough answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23290016/3708242