# NSNumberFormatter set multiplier for dividing with large number

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I have a NSNumberFormatter and I would like to display currency as in a Billion,
So if I have 1,000,000,000 $ I would like to display 1B $

I create NSNumberFormatter object and set multiplyer :

```
NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[numberFormatter setMultiplier: @(1.0/1000000000)];
```

If I display multiplier as:

```
NSLog(@" NUMBER  %@", numberFormatter.multiplier); //  -->  NUMBER  1e-09
```

But if I put

```
NSLog(@"Formatter %@", [numberFormatter1 stringFromNumber:@(1225245041496000)]); // --> Formatter 0
```

It seams to me that multiplier round number but I don't know how to prevent this.

Comment: Similar question here, with several answers. Should be pretty straightforward to get to your goal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267211/ios-convert-large-numbers-to-smaller-format

Comment: Hi, I don't have problems with displaying right suffix but the fact that multiplayer is too small and it is rounded to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're exceeding the minimum value allowed for the `multiplier`. I can't find docs on it, but quick testing shows:

```
[numberFormatter setMultiplier: @(1.0 / 8388608.0)];
```

works fine, but

```
[numberFormatter setMultiplier: @(1.0 / 8388609.0)];
```

fails (string output is always "0").

So I don't think `NSNumberFormatter` is going to fit your needs.