# Abbreviate a localized number in JavaScript for thousands (1k) and millions (1m)

Tags: javascript, instagram

I am using the following Javascript to display my Instagram follower count on my site.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /* 
        Get access token & ID through http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token
        Register your app here @ Instagram http://instagram.com/developer 
        */
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: true,
            url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{ID}/?access_token={ACCES_TOKEN}",
            success: function(data) {
                var ig_count = data.data.counts.followed_by.toString();
                ig_count = add_commas(ig_count);
                $(".instagram_count").html(ig_count);
            }
        });

        function add_commas(number) {
            if (number.length > 3) {
                var mod = number.length % 3;
                var output = (mod > 0 ? (number.substring(0, mod)) : '');
                for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(number.length / 3); i++) {
                    if ((mod == 0) && (i == 0)) {
                        output += number.substring(mod + 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3);
                    } else {
                        output += ',' + number.substring(mod + 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3);
                    }
                }
                return (output);
            } else {
                return number;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<span class="instagram_count"> </span>
```

As you can see, there is a function to add comma's where necessary. I'd like to also display the follower count abbreviated, for example, **3,291** followers as **3.2k**, in another class. So keeping the full follower count in one class and the abbreviated in another. I am not the greatest at JavaScript but am slowly learning.

I have found a similar question ([Is there a way to round numbers into a reader friendly format? (e.g. $1.1k)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685911/is-there-a-way-to-round-numbers-into-a-reader-friendly-format-e-g-1-1k)) but have had no luck implementing it into my JavaScript.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Always keep the detailed count in memory. Use `add_commas()` and similar only for *displaying*.

Comment: *3,291 followers as 3.2k* <-- 3291 should round to 3.3k actually.

Comment: How did you try to use the code from the other question you found? Please show us your attempt.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function intlFormat(num)
{
  return new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Math.round(num*10)/10);
}
function makeFriendly(num)
{
  if(num >= 1000000)
    return intlFormat(num/1000000)+'M';
  if(num >= 1000)
    return intlFormat(num/1000)+'k';
  return intlFormat(num);
}
```

Yields:

```
makeFriendly(1234567)
"1.2M"
makeFriendly(123457)
"123.5k"
makeFriendly(1237)
"1.2k"
makeFriendly(127)
"127"
```

[`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) is the Javascript standard 'package' for implemented internationalized behaviours. [`Intl.NumberFormatter` is specifically the localized number formatter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat). So this code actually respects your locally configured thousands and decimal separators.

Comment: But then the suffixes aren't localized.

Comment: The friendly number is rounded up. 28.551 results in 28.6.

Comment: @glen-84 the suffixes are actually internationally standardized.

Answer (score 12):

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { 
  notation: "compact", 
  compactDisplay: "short" 
})

console.log(formatter.format(9876))
```

output `9.9K`

Credit : [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#scientific_engineering_or_compact_notations)