# Convert long number into abbreviated string in JavaScript, with a special shortness requirement

Tags: javascript, numbers

In JavaScript, how would one write a function that converts a given [edit: *positive integer*] number (below 100 billion) into a 3-letter abbreviation -- where 0-9 and a-z/A-Z are counting as a letter, but the dot (as it's so tiny in many proportional fonts) would not, and would be ignored in terms of the letter limit?

This question is related to [this helpful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685911/is-there-a-way-round-numbers-into-a-friendly-format-e-g-1-1k), but it's not the same; for instance, where that function would turn e.g. "123456 -> 1.23k" ("123.5k" being 5 letters) I am looking for something that does "123456 -> 0.1m" ("0[.]1m" being 3 letters). For instance, this would be the output of hoped function (left original, right ideal return value):

```
0                      "0"
12                    "12"
123                  "123"
1234                "1.2k"
12345                "12k"
123456              "0.1m"
1234567             "1.2m"
12345678             "12m"
123456789           "0.1b"
1234567899          "1.2b"
12345678999          "12b"
```

Thanks!

**Update: Thanks! An answer is in and works per the requirements when the following amendments are made:**

```
function abbreviateNumber(value) {
    var newValue = value;
    if (value >= 1000) {
        var suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"];
        var suffixNum = Math.floor( (""+value).length/3 );
        var shortValue = '';
        for (var precision = 2; precision >= 1; precision--) {
            shortValue = parseFloat( (suffixNum != 0 ? (value / Math.pow(1000,suffixNum) ) : value).toPrecision(precision));
            var dotLessShortValue = (shortValue + '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
            if (dotLessShortValue.length <= 2) { break; }
        }
        if (shortValue % 1 != 0)  shortValue = shortValue.toFixed(1);
        newValue = shortValue+suffixes[suffixNum];
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

Comment: While not JS, I've done the same in C++, which you can view at https://gist.github.com/1870641 -- the process will be the same.  You might be better off looking for off-the-shelf solutions, though.

Comment: Baz, my current start is just a mildly reformatted function from the linked thread, with mentioned issues. Before I'd try to spice up that function, I was hoping someone else might perhaps already have a smart function written somewhere, or knows how to easily do that. Csl, that's great, thanks a lot! Would that conversion also do the "0.1m" style mentioned?

Comment: I have migrated my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10600491/711085

Comment: what's `shortNum` ? you never use is, and it's not even declared..

Comment: Also there's a mix between `.` and `,`, so `1001.5` is turned to millions instead of thousands.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I believe ninjagecko's solution doesn't quite conform with the standard you wanted. The following function does:

```
function intToString (value) {
    var suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"];
    var suffixNum = Math.floor((""+value).length/3);
    var shortValue = parseFloat((suffixNum != 0 ? (value / Math.pow(1000,suffixNum)) : value).toPrecision(2));
    if (shortValue % 1 != 0) {
        shortValue = shortValue.toFixed(1);
    }
    return shortValue+suffixes[suffixNum];
}
```

For values greater than 99 trillion no letter will be added, which can be easily fixed by appending to the 'suffixes' array.

**Edit by Philipp follows:** With the following changes it fits with all requirements perfectly!

```
function abbreviateNumber(value) {
    var newValue = value;
    if (value >= 1000) {
        var suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"];
        var suffixNum = Math.floor( (""+value).length/3 );
        var shortValue = '';
        for (var precision = 2; precision >= 1; precision--) {
            shortValue = parseFloat( (suffixNum != 0 ? (value / Math.pow(1000,suffixNum) ) : value).toPrecision(precision));
            var dotLessShortValue = (shortValue + '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
            if (dotLessShortValue.length <= 2) { break; }
        }
        if (shortValue % 1 != 0)  shortValue = shortValue.toFixed(1);
        newValue = shortValue+suffixes[suffixNum];
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I made some amendments so it fits 100% with the requirements and edited your answer (I hope that is the correct way to do it in StackOverflow, please change if needed). Superb!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: which case/requirement did I miss?

Comment: Those were minor and quickly amended based on your great answer. The following test numbers were slightly missed: 
123 became 0.12k (ideal result: 123, as that's still 3 letters and thus ok); 123456 became 0.12m (ideal: 0.1m, as 0.12m is 4 letters, minus dot); same for 0.12b which with amendments now becomes 0.1b. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I just made a small adjustment to it (yet to be peer reviewed). I added value = Math.round(value); to the very start of the function. By doing that it doesn't break when "value" has decimal places eg. 10025.26584 will turn into 10k instead of NaN

Comment: Its returning NaN in some cases..!!

Comment: abbreviateNumber(9999000) returns "10m" instead of "9.9m"

Comment: lacs is missing

Comment: `shortNum` is not defined in the @PhilippLenssen's edit at the end `if (shortValue % 1 != 0)  shortNum = shortValue.toFixed(1);`

Comment: This did not give me the results I was expecting. 200,000 should have rendered as 200K, not 0.2M. The answer below this seems more robust.

Comment: @jamesmfriedman Did you read the question? This was the desired output by OP.

Comment: This answer inspired this `const shortNumber = (num) => {       var newnum = String(num); var app = null; var decimal = null; const suff = ["", "k", "m", "b", "t"];       for (let i = 0; i < suff.length; i++) {         if (newnum.length > 3) {           decimal = newnum[newnum.length - 3];           newnum = newnum.substring(0, newnum.length - 3);         } else {           app = i;           break;         }       }       return newnum + "." + (decimal ? "." + decimal : "") + suff[app];     };` onto which the op can just prefix a 0 if `if(shortNumber(.99).startsWith("."))` @jamesmfriedman

Comment: It can't deal with rational numbers (eg. 24572752353.1)  :(

Comment: How to return `200K` instead of `0.2M`? Should I use the other answer?

Comment: I would add `if (Math.abs(value) >= 1000)`  instead `if (value >= 1000)` to have support for negative values as well

Answer (score 111):

### Approach 1: Built-in library

I would recommend using Javascript's built-in library method [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

```js
const formatCash = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  notation: "compact",
  maximumFractionDigits: 1
}).format(2500);

console.log(formatCash);
```

### Approach 2: No library

But you can also create these abbreviations with simple `if` statements, and without the complexity of `Math`, `maps`, `regex`, `for`-loops, etc.

**Formatting Cash value with K**

```js
const formatCash = n => {
  if (n < 1e3) return n;
  if (n >= 1e3) return +(n / 1e3).toFixed(1) + "K";
};

console.log(formatCash(2500));
```

**Formatting Cash value with K M B T**

```js
const formatCash = n => {
  if (n < 1e3) return n;
  if (n >= 1e3 && n < 1e6) return +(n / 1e3).toFixed(1) + "K";
  if (n >= 1e6 && n < 1e9) return +(n / 1e6).toFixed(1) + "M";
  if (n >= 1e9 && n < 1e12) return +(n / 1e9).toFixed(1) + "B";
  if (n >= 1e12) return +(n / 1e12).toFixed(1) + "T";
};

console.log(formatCash(1235000));
```

**Using negative numbers**

```js
let format = '';
const number = -1235000;

if (number < 0) {
  format = '-' + formatCash(-1 * number);
} else {
  format = formatCash(number);
}
```

Answer (score 59):

This handles very large values as well and is a bit more succinct and efficient.

```
abbreviate_number = function(num, fixed) {
  if (num === null) { return null; } // terminate early
  if (num === 0) { return '0'; } // terminate early
  fixed = (!fixed || fixed < 0) ? 0 : fixed; // number of decimal places to show
  var b = (num).toPrecision(2).split("e"), // get power
      k = b.length === 1 ? 0 : Math.floor(Math.min(b[1].slice(1), 14) / 3), // floor at decimals, ceiling at trillions
      c = k < 1 ? num.toFixed(0 + fixed) : (num / Math.pow(10, k * 3) ).toFixed(1 + fixed), // divide by power
      d = c < 0 ? c : Math.abs(c), // enforce -0 is 0
      e = d + ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T'][k]; // append power
  return e;
}
```

Results:

```
for(var a='', i=0; i < 14; i++){ 
    a += i; 
    console.log(a, abbreviate_number(parseInt(a),0)); 
    console.log(-a, abbreviate_number(parseInt(-a),0)); 
}

0 0
-0 0
01 1
-1 -1
012 12
-12 -12
0123 123
-123 -123
01234 1.2K
-1234 -1.2K
012345 12.3K
-12345 -12.3K
0123456 123.5K
-123456 -123.5K
01234567 1.2M
-1234567 -1.2M
012345678 12.3M
-12345678 -12.3M
0123456789 123.5M
-123456789 -123.5M
012345678910 12.3B
-12345678910 -12.3B
01234567891011 1.2T
-1234567891011 -1.2T
0123456789101112 123.5T
-123456789101112 -123.5T
012345678910111213 12345.7T
-12345678910111212 -12345.7T
```

Comment: I like this approach because it handles non-integers much better than the other answers.

Comment: Much better solution

Comment: For very small values (e.g. `5e-18`), this returns "0T", so I added this: `if (num < 1e-3) { return '~0'; }`

Comment: I recently ran into the same problem in Python and quickly came up with a much simpler approach (I guess my thinking has changed in the last 5 years). In case it's helpful, here it is; I'd love to see it in JS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65084005/1438550

Comment: very good, much accurate

Answer (score 35):

The modern, easy, built-in, highly customizable, and 'no-code' way: [Intl.FormatNumber](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) 's [format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/format) function ([compatibility graph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Browser_compatibility))

```
var numbers = [98721, 9812730,37462,29,093484620123, 9732,0283737718234712]
for(let num of numbers){
  console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat( 'en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 1,notation: "compact" , compactDisplay: "short" }).format(num));
}
98.7K
9.8M
37.5K
29
93.5B
9.7K
283.7T
```

Notes:

- And a list of all the keys in the `options` parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#parameters
- When using `style: 'currency'`, you must remove maximumFractionDigits, as it will figure this out for you.

Answer (score 19):

Here's what I think is a fairly elegant solution. **It does not attempt to deal with negative numbers**:

```
const COUNT_ABBRS = [ '', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y' ];

function formatCount(count, withAbbr = false, decimals = 2) {
    const i     = 0 === count ? count : Math.floor(Math.log(count) / Math.log(1000));
    let result  = parseFloat((count / Math.pow(1000, i)).toFixed(decimals));
    if(withAbbr) {
        result += `${COUNT_ABBRS[i]}`; 
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Examples**:

```
   formatCount(1000, true);
=> '1k'
   formatCount(100, true);
=> '100'
   formatCount(10000, true);
=> '10k'
   formatCount(10241, true);
=> '10.24k'
   formatCount(10241, true, 0);
=> '10k'
   formatCount(10241, true, 1)
=> '10.2k'
   formatCount(1024111, true, 1)
=> '1M'
   formatCount(1024111, true, 2)
=> '1.02M'
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the question as posed, but it's just what _I_ am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I like the SI-symbols better than k, m, b. 1b in America/UK is 1e9, but 1e12 in many other countries.

Answer (score 13):

I think you cant try this [numeraljs/](http://numeraljs.com/)
If you want convert 1000 to 1k

```
console.log(numeral(1000).format('0a'));
```

and if you want convert 123400 to 123.4k try this

```
console.log(numeral(123400).format('0.0a'));
```

Comment: Fantastic solution if you're willing to install a third-party library

Comment: Is there a way to use `0.0a` but show `1k` not `1.0k` when the number is 1000? (Trimming the zeros)

Answer (score 7):

Based on my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600491/711085 , your answer is actually slightly shorter to implement, by using `.substring(0,3)`:

```
function format(n) {
    with (Math) {
        var base = floor(log(abs(n))/log(1000));
        var suffix = 'kmb'[base-1];
        return suffix ? String(n/pow(1000,base)).substring(0,3)+suffix : ''+n;
    }
}
```

(As usual, don't use Math unless you know exactly what you're doing; assigning `var pow=...` and the like would cause insane bugs. See link for a safer way to do this.)

```
> tests = [-1001, -1, 0, 1, 2.5, 999, 1234, 
           1234.5, 1000001, Math.pow(10,9), Math.pow(10,12)]
> tests.forEach(function(x){ console.log(x,format(x)) })

-1001 "-1.k"
-1 "-1"
0 "0"
1 "1"
2.5 "2.5"
999 "999"
1234 "1.2k"
1234.5 "1.2k"
1000001 "1.0m"
1000000000 "1b"
1000000000000 "1000000000000"
```

You will need to catch the case where the result is >=1 trillion, if your requirement for 3 chars is strict, else you risk creating corrupt data, which would be very bad.

Comment: Nice solution. Also mad props for using the deprecated `with` statement :)

Answer (score 5):

**Code**

```
const SI_PREFIXES = [
  { value: 1, symbol: '' },
  { value: 1e3, symbol: 'k' },
  { value: 1e6, symbol: 'M' },
  { value: 1e9, symbol: 'G' },
  { value: 1e12, symbol: 'T' },
  { value: 1e15, symbol: 'P' },
  { value: 1e18, symbol: 'E' },
]

const abbreviateNumber = (number) => {
  if (number === 0) return number

  const tier = SI_PREFIXES.filter((n) => number >= n.value).pop()
  const numberFixed = (number / tier.value).toFixed(1)

  return `${numberFixed}${tier.symbol}`
}

abbreviateNumber(2000) // "2.0k"
abbreviateNumber(2500) // "2.5k"
abbreviateNumber(255555555) // "255.6M"
```

**Test:**

```
import abbreviateNumber from './abbreviate-number'

test('abbreviateNumber', () => {
  expect(abbreviateNumber(0)).toBe('0')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(100)).toBe('100')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(999)).toBe('999')

  expect(abbreviateNumber(1000)).toBe('1.0k')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(100000)).toBe('100.0k')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(1000000)).toBe('1.0M')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(1e6)).toBe('1.0M')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(1e10)).toBe('10.0G')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(1e13)).toBe('10.0T')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(1e16)).toBe('10.0P')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(1e19)).toBe('10.0E')

  expect(abbreviateNumber(1500)).toBe('1.5k')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(1555)).toBe('1.6k')

  expect(abbreviateNumber(undefined)).toBe('0')
  expect(abbreviateNumber(null)).toBe(null)
  expect(abbreviateNumber('100')).toBe('100')
  expect(abbreviateNumber('1000')).toBe('1.0k')
})
```

Comment: After trying every solution above in this thread, this is the only one that works correctly.  Thanks Danilo!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another take on it. I wanted 123456 to be 123.4K instead of 0.1M

**UPDATE 2022, Dec. 5**

Added support for negative values and non-integer values

```js
function convert(value) {

    var length = (Math.abs(parseInt(value, 10)) + '').length,
        index = Math.ceil((length - 3) / 3),
        suffix = ['K', 'M', 'B', 'T'];

    if (length < 4) return value;
    
    return (value / Math.pow(1000, index))
           .toFixed(1)
           .replace(/\.0$/, '') + suffix[index - 1];

}

var tests = [1234, 7890, -990123467, 123456, 750000.1234, 567890, 800001, 2000000, 20000000, 201234567, 801234567, 1201234567];
for (var i in tests)
    document.writeln('<p>convert(' + tests[i] + ') = ' + convert(tests[i]) + '</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around, this approach seems to meet the required criteria. Takes some inspiration from @chuckator's answer.

```
function abbreviateNumber(value) {

    if (value <= 1000) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    const numDigits = (""+value).length;
    const suffixIndex = Math.floor(numDigits / 3);

    const normalisedValue = value / Math.pow(1000, suffixIndex);

    let precision = 2;
    if (normalisedValue < 1) {
        precision = 1;
    }

    const suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"];
    return normalisedValue.toPrecision(precision) + suffixes[suffixIndex];
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is great. I had a slightly different case where I didn't want to show values with leading zeros.  I added   
    if (adjustedValue.charAt(0) === '0') {
        return adjustedValue * 1000 + suffixes[suffixIndex - 1];
  } else {
    return adjustedValue + suffixes[suffixIndex];
  }

Answer (score 1):

Intl is the Javascript standard 'package' for implemented internationalized behaviours. Intl.NumberFormatter is specifically the localized number formatter. So this code actually respects your locally configured thousands and decimal separators.

```
intlFormat(num) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Math.round(num*10)/10);
}

abbreviateNumber(value) {
    let num = Math.floor(value);
    if(num >= 1000000000)
        return this.intlFormat(num/1000000000)+'B';
    if(num >= 1000000)
        return this.intlFormat(num/1000000)+'M';
    if(num >= 1000)
        return this.intlFormat(num/1000)+'k';
    return this.intlFormat(num);
}
```

abbreviateNumber(999999999999)    // Gives 999B

Related question: [Abbreviate a localized number in JavaScript for thousands (1k) and millions (1m)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611937/abbreviate-a-localized-number-in-javascript-for-thousands-1k-and-millions-1m)

Comment: But then the suffixes aren't localized.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this function to get these values.

```
function Converter(number, fraction) {
    let ranges = [
      { divider: 1, suffix: '' },
      { divider: 1e3, suffix: 'K' },
      { divider: 1e6, suffix: 'M' },
      { divider: 1e9, suffix: 'G' },
      { divider: 1e12, suffix: 'T' },
      { divider: 1e15, suffix: 'P' },
      { divider: 1e18, suffix: 'E' },
    ]
    //find index based on number of zeros
    let index = (Math.abs(number).toString().length / 3).toFixed(0)
    return (number / ranges[index].divider).toFixed(fraction) + ranges[index].suffix
}
```

Each 3 digits has different suffix, that's what i'm trying to find firstly.

So, remove negative symbol **if exists**, then find how many 3 digits in this number.

after that find appropriate suffix based on previous calculation added to divided number.

```
Converter(1500, 1)
```

Will return:

```
1.5K
```

Comment: there's something wrong.


Converter(824492, 1) 

will return 0.8M. It should return 824k

Answer (score 1):

### Use as a Number Prototype

For easy and direct you. Simply make a prototype of it. Here is an example.

```js
Number.prototype.abbr = function (decimal = 2): string {
  const notations = ['', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y'],
    i = Math.floor(Math.log(this) / Math.log(1000));
  return `${parseFloat((this / Math.pow(1000, i)).toFixed(decimal))}${notations[i]}`;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Indian Currency format to **(K, L, C)** Thousand, Lakh, Crore

```
const formatCash = n => {
  if (n < 1e3) return n;
  if (n >= 1e3 && n < 1e5) return +(n / 1e3).toFixed(1) + "K";
  if (n >= 1e5 && n <= 1e6) return +(n / 1e5).toFixed(1) + "L";
  if (n >= 1e6 && n <= 1e9) return +(n / 1e7).toFixed(1) + "C";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

```
const unitlist = ['', 'K', 'M', 'B']
export function AmountConveter (number: number) {
  const sign = Math.sign(number)
  let unit = 0

  while (Math.abs(number) > 1000) {
    unit = unit + 1
    number = Math.floor(Math.abs(number) / 100) / 10
  }
  return sign * Math.abs(number) + unitlist[unit]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another take on it. It replicates YT subscriber count abbreviation.

```js
function countAbbreviation(count) {
    const COUNT_ABBRS = ["", "K", "M", "B", "T"];
    if (count < 1000) {
        return count;
    }
    const i = Math.floor(Math.log(count) / Math.log(1000));
    let result = count / (1000 ** i);
    const digits = Math.floor(Math.log10(result)) + 1;
    const decimals = Math.max(0, 3 - digits);
    result = result.toFixed(decimals);
    result = result + COUNT_ABBRS[i];
    return result;
}


console.log(countAbbreviation(102))
console.log(countAbbreviation(1002))
console.log(countAbbreviation(10002))
console.log(countAbbreviation(100002))
console.log(countAbbreviation(1000002))
console.log(countAbbreviation(10000002))
console.log(countAbbreviation(100000002))
console.log(countAbbreviation(1000000002))
```

```
// 102
// 1.00K
// 10.0K
// 100K
// 1.00M
// 10.0M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            function converse_number (labelValue) {

                    // Nine Zeroes for Billions
                    return Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+9

                    ? Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+9 + "B"
                    // Six Zeroes for Millions 
                    : Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+6

                    ? Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+6 + "M"
                    // Three Zeroes for Thousands
                    : Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+3

                    ? Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+3 + "K"

                    : Math.abs(Number(labelValue));

                }
```

alert(converse_number(100000000000));

Answer (score 0):

@nimesaram

Your solution will not be desirable for the following case:

```
Input 50000
Output 50.0k
```

---

Following solution will work fine.

```
const convertNumberToShortString = (
  number: number,
  fraction: number
) => {
  let newValue: string = number.toString();
  if (number >= 1000) {
    const ranges = [
      { divider: 1, suffix: '' },
      { divider: 1e3, suffix: 'k' },
      { divider: 1e6, suffix: 'm' },
      { divider: 1e9, suffix: 'b' },
      { divider: 1e12, suffix: 't' },
      { divider: 1e15, suffix: 'p' },
      { divider: 1e18, suffix: 'e' }
    ];
    //find index based on number of zeros
    const index = Math.floor(Math.abs(number).toString().length / 3);
    let numString = (number / ranges[index].divider).toFixed(fraction);
    numString =
      parseInt(numString.substring(numString.indexOf('.') + 1)) === 0
        ? Math.floor(number / ranges[index].divider).toString()
        : numString;
    newValue = numString + ranges[index].suffix;
  }
  return newValue;
};

// Input 50000
// Output 50k
// Input 4500
// Output 4.5k
```

Comment: A note: Except k for Kilo, all prefixes are uppercase. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_prefix

Comment: Oh, Thanks! Actually my use case needs everything in small letters.

Answer (score 0):

### Even more *Abbreviation?*

Let's make "Qa" as Quadrillions and "Qi" as Quintillions... maybe "Sx" Sextillions, and So on...

```
if (num >= 1e3 !& num >= 1e6) {num2 = num/1e3 + "K";};
if (num >= 1e6 !& num >= 1e9) {num2 = num/1e6 + "M";};
if (num >= 1e9 !& num >= 1e12) {num2 = num/1e9 + "B";};
if (num >= 1e12 !& num >= 1e15) {num2 = num/1e12 + "T";};
if (num >= 1e15 !& num >= 1e18) {num2 = num/1e15 + "Qa";};
if (num >= 1e18 !& num >= 1e21) {num2 = num/1e18 + "Qi";};
if (num >= 1e21 !& num >= 1e24) {num2 = num/1e21 + "Sx";};
if (num >= 1e24 !& num >= 1e27) {num2 = num/1e24 + "Sp";};
if (num >= 1e27 !& num >= 1e30) {num2 = num/1e27 + "Oc";};
if (num >= 1e30 !& num >= 1e93) {num2 = num/1e30 + "No";};
if (num >= 1e33 !& num >= 1e36) {num2 = num/1e33 + "Dc";};
if (num >= 1e36 !& num >= 1e39) {num2 = num/1e36 + "UDc";};
if (num >= 1e39) {num2 = num/1e39 + "DDc";};
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the Recursive and shorter version using Pure JS for those who are interested:

```js
const abbCharacters = ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T'];
const shortenNumber = (num, stack = 0) => {
  if (Math.abs(num) < 1000 || stack >= abbCharacters.length - 1) return num + abbCharacters[stack];

  return shortenNumber(Math.round(num / 1000), ++stack);
};
```

Result:

```
console.log(shortenNumber(100)); //100
console.log(shortenNumber(-100)); //-100
console.log(shortenNumber(9023)); //9k
console.log(shortenNumber(-9023)); //-9k
console.log(shortenNumber(213423)); //213k
console.log(shortenNumber(-23945523)); //-24M
console.log(shortenNumber(5555232323549455)); //5555T
console.log(shortenNumber(-5555232323549455)); //-5555T
```

Answer (score -2):

## Pure Javascript

`n` --> `292234567890` to `292,234,567,890`

`s`  --> `292,234,567,890` to `292,234,567,890` + `K` | `M` | `B` | `T` | `q` | `Q` | `s` | `S` | `o` | `n` | `d` | `U`

`s`  --> `292,234,567,890B` to `292.2B`

`return`  --> `Remove 4th digit` `292.2B` to `292B`

```js
function format(n) {n=n.toLocaleString();
  let s = n+('KMBTqQsSondU'.split('')[n.split(',').length-2]||'')
  s = s.replace(/,([1-9])[\d,.]+|,[\d,.]+/g,(m,a)=>a?'.'+a:'')
  return s.replace(/(\d{3})\.\d/, '$1');
}


//Just for show
let negative = [-1991078910902345678907890, -991708910902345678907890,-10902345678907890, -1000234567890, -1234567890, -12345678, -1234567, -12345, -1234, -123, -12, -1, 0]
let positive = [1991078910902345678907890, 991078910902345678907890,10902345678907890, 1000234567890, 1234567890, 12345678, 1234567, 12345, 1234, 123, 12, 1, 0]
let table = '<table cellspacing="0"><tbody>';
negative.forEach(function(x){ table += '<tr><td style="padding-right: 30px;">'+x+'</td><td>'+ format(x)+'</td></tr>'})
table +='</tbody></table><table cellspacing="0"><tbody>'
positive.forEach(function(x){ table += '<tr><td style="padding-right: 30px;">'+x+'</td><td>'+ format(x)+'</td></tr>'})
document.body.innerHTML = table+'</tbody></table>';
```

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #f8f8f8;}
td {padding: 5px 10px;}
table {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-table;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

## Pure Javascript

Pros: `Native Built in Solution`
Cons: `Maxes out at Trillion`

```js
function format(x) {let o={maximumFractionDigits: 1,notation: "compact",compactDisplay: "short"};
  let a=x<0,n=x*Math.sign(x);s=new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', o).format(n);return a?'-'+s:s;
}



//Just for show
let negative = [-1991078910902345678907890, -991078910902345678907890,-10902345678907890, -1000234567890, -1234567890, -12345678, -1234567, -12345, -1234, -123, -12, -1, 0]
let positive = [1991078910902345678907890, 991078910902345678907890,10902345678907890, 1000234567890, 1234567890, 12345678, 1234567, 12345, 1234, 123, 12, 1, 0]
let table = '<table cellspacing="0"><tbody>';
negative.forEach(function(x){ table += '<tr><td style="padding-right: 10px;">'+x+'</td><td>'+ format(x)+'</td></tr>'})
table +='</tbody></table><table cellspacing="0"><tbody>'
positive.forEach(function(x){ table += '<tr><td style="padding-right: 10px;">'+x+'</td><td>'+ format(x)+'</td></tr>'})
document.body.innerHTML = table+'</tbody></table>';
```

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #f8f8f8;}
td {padding: 5px 10px;}
table {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-table;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```