# Javascript to turn 110,000 into 110K and not 0.11M

Tags: javascript

To start with you need...

```
function m(n,d){x=(''+n).length,p=Math.pow,d=p(10,d)
x-=x%3
return Math.round(n*d/p(10,x))/d+" kMGTPE"[x/3]}
```

Then calling like so...

```
// m( ANY NUMBER HERE or VAR LIKE I USE,HOW DECIMAL PLACES)
m(110000,2)
```

However instead of the above's result of 0.11M, I would like it to display 110k.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10601315/4161269

Comment: On this, 30404 results not with 30K but 30.k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is an example of an overly optimized script, lets make it more developer friendly an readable

```
function metricPrefix(rawNumber,decimalPlaces){
    var sufixes= " kMFGPE";
    var numberLength =(''+n).length;
    decimalPlaces=Math.pow(10,d); //raise 10 to the number of decimal places
    var modLen = numberLength - numberLength%3;
    var sufix = sufixes[modLen/3];
return Math.round(rawNumber*decimalPlaces/decimalPlaces(10,modLen))/decimalPlaces+ sufix;
}
```

Now it's easier to work with. We can see the issue is that we need to adjust for when the string is divisible by 3, so lets fix that.

```js
function metricPrefix(rawNumber,decimalPlaces){
        var sufixes= " kMFGPE";        
        var numberLength =(''+rawNumber).length;
        decimalPlaces=Math.pow(10,decimalPlaces); //raise 10 to the number of decimal places
        //THis is the change
        //If the length is divisable by 3 take 3 off the length
        var modLen = numberLength%3 == 0 ? numberLength - 3 - (numberLength%3)  :  numberLength - (numberLength%3);
        console.log(modLen);
        var sufix = sufixes[(modLen/3)]
        console.log(sufix)
    return Math.round(rawNumber*decimalPlaces/Math.pow(10,modLen))/decimalPlaces+ sufix;
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result").html(metricPrefix(110000,2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```