# How to display number apprevation in jsonata if 1000 men's k 1000000 as M

Tags: json, jsonata

How to display abbreviations in json instead of displaying  full values if 10,000 as 10 k if 123000000 as 123 M

How to display abbreviations in json instead of displaying  full values if 10,000 as 10 k if 123000000 as 123 M

Comment: AFAIK, there's no built-in functionality to do this. You will likely need to define and register a custom function (see [Programming constructs](https://docs.jsonata.org/programming) and [Embedding and Extending JSONata](https://docs.jsonata.org/embedding-extending)) and then write the code to do it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980688/664577 for how to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Could provide me example code in jsonata

Comment: I can have a look (or someone else from the community eventually will), but to be able to help you in a more concrete way, please provide a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please make sure to edit your tags and mark the programming language that you are using besides JSONata (there are bindings for many languages). Once you do, leave a comment here.