# Display number in Million or Thousand format in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am trying to display number format in my angular 4 application. Basically what i am looking at is if the number is in 12.23 millions then it should display For e.g
12.2M (One decimal place)

If the number is 50,000.123 then 50.1K

How do i achieve that in angular. Do I need to write a directive ? Are there any inbuilt pipes in angular ?

structure

```
export interface NpvResults  {

            captiveInsYear: number[];
            captiveInsPremiumPaid: number[];
            captiveInsTaxDeduction: number[];
            captiveInsLoanToParent: number[];
            captiveInsCapitalContribution: number[];
            captiveDividentDistribution: number[];
            captiveInsTerminalValue: number[];

        }
```

The array is initialized to the following value

```
this.sourceResults.captiveInsPremiumPaid = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

The html

```
<td *ngFor= "let item of NpvResults.captiveInsPremiumPaid" >{{item}}</td>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685911/is-there-a-way-to-round-numbers-into-a-reader-friendly-format-e-g-1-1k check here for answer

Answer (score 61):

you can create **PIPE**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'thousandSuff'
})
export class ThousandSuffixesPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(input: any, args?: any): any {
    var exp, rounded,
      suffixes = ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E'];

    if (Number.isNaN(input)) {
      return null;
    }

    if (input < 1000) {
      return input;
    }

    exp = Math.floor(Math.log(input) / Math.log(1000));

    return (input / Math.pow(1000, exp)).toFixed(args) + suffixes[exp - 1];


  }

}
```

implement in the view

```
{{ model | thousandSuff  }} <!-- 0 decimals -->

{{ model | thousandSuff : 2  }}  <!-- X decimals -->
```

result

> {{ 22600000 | thousandSuff  }} -> 23M
>
> {{ 22600000 | thousandSuff : 2  }} ->   22.60M

Comment: it works pefect but if you have 1.565656 and fix the number till 2 decimals  with the args argument It perform a round and the result is 1.6, so to get 1.5 you have to do this.    return (input / Math.pow(1000, exp)).toFixed(args+1).slice(0, (args*-1)) + suffixes[exp - 1];

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here I just give you an idea first create 
**Html**
`{{number | shortNumber}}`
you can create your own `custom pipe filter` in which you can pass your number in the pipe and then, you can do code like below, put this logic in your custom pipe.

**Pipe filter**

```
getformat(){
    if(number == 0) {
    return 0;
}
else
{        
  // hundreds
  if(number <= 999){
    return number ;
  }
  // thousands
  else if(number >= 1000 && number <= 999999){
    return (number / 1000) + 'K';
  }
  // millions
  else if(number >= 1000000 && number <= 999999999){
    return (number / 1000000) + 'M';
  }
  // billions
  else if(number >= 1000000000 && number <= 999999999999){
    return (number / 1000000000) + 'B';
  }
  else
    return number ;
  }
}
```

you can do like this.For creating custom pipe you can refer to this site[click here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Comment: Its been quite helpful however the numbers could be in negative as well. i.e negative thousand, negative , million and negative billion

Comment: This pipe example will handle negative numbers: https://medium.com/@thunderroid/angular-short-number-suffix-pipe-1k-2m-3b-dded4af82fb4

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to make a pipe and a service. You can do the actually formatting in service using numeral js library and import that service in the pipe and apply formatting in transform method.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { NumberFormatService } from '../utils/number-format.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'numberFormat'
})
export class NumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private nF: NumberFormatService) {}

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(args == "commas"){
      return this.nF.addCommas(value);
    }
    else if(args == "kmb"){
      return this.nF.addKMB(value);
    }
    return value;
  }

}

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as numeral from 'numeral';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NumberFormatService {

  constructor() { }

  public addCommas(val){
    return numeral(val).format('0,0');
  }

  public addKMB(val){
    return numeral(val).format('0[.]00a');
  }
}

html template file
{{dailyData.avgDaily | numberFormat: 'commas'}}
{{dailyData.avgDaily | numberFormat: 'kmb'}}
```

1. You can get numeral js dependency documentation from official site [link](http://numeraljs.com/).
2. You can install numeraljs in the angular application using npm install numeral --save

Comment: What is the rationale behind creating a service and not doing the numeral.js stuff inside the pipe itself? Does it have anything to do with parallel execution/performance or is it to also make the formatting logic available to Typescript code via the service?

Comment: Pipes are basically meant to be used in the templates. The main reason behind creating a service is just splitting the pipe and the data formatting logic. If you create a service, you can also re-use the service from other components, directives, or service itself. But depends on your requirements, there is no any strict standards that you need to follow and I don't think it will impact anything.

Answer (score 0):

I write the below pipe, it will handle all of the negative scenarios( **Negative numbers, Strings, blank**) as well. [And works best in all of the cases. Complete Article here.](https://medium.com/@nimishgoel056/display-number-in-billion-million-thousand-using-custom-pipe-in-angular-b95bf388350a)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'numberSuffix'
})
export class NumberSuffixPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: any, args?: any): any {
    let exp;
    const suffixes = ['K', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'P', 'E'];
    const isNagtiveValues = input < 0;
    if (Number.isNaN(input) || (input < 1000 && input >= 0) || !this.isNumeric(input) || (input < 0 && input > -1000)) {
      if (!!args && this.isNumeric(input) && !(input < 0) && input != 0) {
        return input.toFixed(args);
      } else {
        return input;
      }
    }

    if (!isNagtiveValues) {
      exp = Math.floor(Math.log(input) / Math.log(1000));

      return (input / Math.pow(1000, exp)).toFixed(args) + suffixes[exp - 1];
    } else {
      input = input * -1;

      exp = Math.floor(Math.log(input) / Math.log(1000));

      return (input * -1 / Math.pow(1000, exp)).toFixed(args) + suffixes[exp - 1];
    }
  }
  isNumeric(value): boolean {
    if (value < 0) value = value * -1;
    if (/^-{0,1}\d+$/.test(value)) {
      return true;
    } else if (/^\d+\.\d+$/.test(value)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```